# Dependency triangle

Tags: go, types, dependencies, glide-golang

Dependencies is an issue for Go but this is something new:

- Application `A` directly dependent on libraries `B` and `C`
- Library `B` directly dependent on library `C`

If we have something like this in code of the application `A`:

```
funcyInstance := &C.FuncyObject{}
B.CleverFunction(funcyInstance)
```

When in lib `B`:

```
func CleverFunction(arg *C.FuncyObject) {}
```

It raises an error:

> cannot use funcyInstance (type "*A/vendor/github.com/C".FuncyObject) as type "*B/vendor/github.com/C".FuncyObject in argument to B.CleverFunction

I'm using Glide as a dependency manager.

I understand that this configuration of dependencies causes existence of several types instead of a single one (for all library) and possibly it is just an anti pattern for Go. Anyway... How to solve the issue?

Comment: You should never have nested vendor directories. It looks like `glide` has a `--strip-vendor` option, rather than doing it be default for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd remove the `vendor` folder below `B`, and put `C` in the root `vendor` folder (for application `A` if I am getting your structure correctly).

That way, you only end up with one place for each type.

Not sure why `B` would have a `vendor` folder in the first place, since Glide's recommendations are clear on this:

http://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vendor/

> Libraries (codebases without a main package) should not store outside packages in a vendor/ folder

and

> In applications (codebases with a main package) there should only be one vendor/ directory at the top level